# The basic framework behind a simple web app, what to use where

Tags: ajax, web-applications, animation

okay so i have basic skills in html, css, javascript.

im still in the learning phases but just need a little help on where to go in regards to creating a web app.
i can figure out all the code, so thats fine, i just need some pointers as to what to use where.

So basically ill have a webpage with a few simple buttons, when clicked they'll send a message to the server and the server will hold a count for each button clicked using a php script.

1) - would it be best to hold that information in a JSON file?

then from there, there'll be another webpage which will have div tags stretching 100% across the page, with an element inside it which will move across the page according to the count held on the server.

2) - what should i use to animate it moving?. would i use javascript? or css3 or something?

the front end will need to continuously update on the count held by the server.

3) - would AJAX methods be best using javascript?

any advice would be great thanks.

And one last thing.
With Javascript animating, if i wanted to animate a div moving horizontal, is the best way to do it by animating the margin size? or am i stuck in the dark days..

Answer (score 1):

1: i would store it in a database, if you store it in a file make sure that you are handling writes in a safe way(multiple writes to the same file)

2:you could use javascript to animate the css properties of a html element(preferable the width)

3: Ajax would work but then you need to continuously poll the server for changes alternativly use longpoling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

an alternative if you only support modern browsers and your hosting company allows it is to use websockets

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're trying to save information server side (which you seem to be), I would recommend using a database (such as MySQL).
2. If your animation is dependent on the value from the server, I would use javascript to animate it. Note that you will have to poll the server in order to actually get this information (lets say, every second). When you get the information, simply update the div you want to animate with the new information. I don't quite understand what you want your display to look like, so I can't really give you anything more specific here.
3. Yes. I would recommend using jQuery to handle your AJAX calls as it makes it much easier and deals with cross-browser weird-ities.

To your update:
  One option could definately be to adjust the (left) margin size, but you could also use the relative position. It will basically push the element however many pixels in whatever position from where it would typically be displayed. So if your box is by default right along the left border, you could relatively position it 100px to the right. You can read more about position [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).